# Fade all anchors except for specific anchor with class

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have this basis page fading script function that currently targets all anchors ('a'), but not sure how exactly exclude a certain anchor with a class (.noFade) from fading out.

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // to fade in on page load
    $("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").fadeIn(400); 

    // to fade out before redirect
    $('a').click(function(e){
        redirect = $(this).attr('href');
        e.preventDefault();

        $('body').fadeOut(400, function(){
            document.location.href = redirect
        });
    });
})
```

Thanks in advance!
UPDATE: Thank you, all of these answers are correct and work.

Comment: `$('a:not(.noFade)').click` ?

Comment: Yes that's actually what I needed, for some reason I was thinking an if statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **[`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** selector :

```
$('a:not(".noFade")') //All anchors that has no class noFade
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('a:not(".noFade")').click(function(){
    alert("targeted");
})
```

```css
a{
  color: green;
  
}

a.noFade{
   color: red;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#" class="noFade">2</a>
<a href="#">3</a>
<a href="#">4</a>
<a href="#" class="noFade">5</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `:not()`: https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

```
$('a:not(.noFade)').click(function(e){
    redirect = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').fadeOut(400, function(){
        document.location.href = redirect
     });
   });
 })
```